# How can 'spaces of production' possess ethics? - p 146, Mark Shepherd

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Walter Benjamin’s massive torso, The Arcades Project (1999), was one of the fi rst works
>   to actively theorize the relationship between space, aesthetics and consumption. The
>   architecture of the arcade, popularized by the Parisian Haussmann architecture,
>   precedes the late modern aesthetic of consumer space. In the arcade, the goods are on
>   display at the same times as the fl âneur is capable of passing through the arcade as an
>   autonomous, enterprising and choosing subject. Consumption becomes an aesthetic
>   experience; space and consumption are merged in the special practice producing
>   spaces of consumption. The visual qualities of the arcade architecture enable a
>   spatialization of the goods, a displacement and spatial distribution in consumer space.
>   <sup>[I later added everything else before this, for context.]</sup> Therefore, the arcade is one of the first distinct urban spaces; spaces of production are
>   characterized by rural aesthetics and **[ethics](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ethics)** emphasizing accumulation, the physical
>   transformation of nature. The spaces of production are **paradoxically** rural spaces
>   located within urban environments... The arcade is overturning this assemblage of aesthetics and **ethics** and
>   makes consumption a spatial practice distinguished from that of the spaces of
>   production. The space of consumption is thus characterized by its loss of facticity; its
>   ontological status is never once and for all determined – a certain degree of uncertainty
>   is always present in consumption because of its symbolic qualities.

How does it make sense for ethics (moral principles) to feature in 'spaces of production'? 
Funnily enough, I find this use paradoxical. But for what does the passage use **paradoxically**? Please explain the steps or thought processes, so that I can try to resolve by myself in the future?

Source: 40% down para 1, [p 146](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false), *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Comment: Did the original really say "Walter Benjamin's massive torso"? A "torso" is the part of the body other than the head, arms, and legs. Saying that Walter Benjamin has a massive torso sounds like you're saying that he's fat. I wonder if the original didn't say "tome". Or perhaps this is another definition of "torso" that I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

### Use of "Ethics"

This author is using ethics differently than it's common usage. Shepherd claims that in France before the popularization of arcades, rural spaces that were using nature to produce goods were seen as beautiful or **ethical** - meaning pure and good. This is contrasted with the idea of the city, where people consume instead of making and which is dirty, sinful, or unethical.

Shepherd isn't actually claiming this view of "ethics" is correct. He is not saying that rural spaces were actually good and that urban spaces were actually bad, just that the view at that time in France was such.

He goes on to say that arcades began to change this view. They were beautiful spaces that enabled consumerism, and so the idea of nature being "good" or "ethical" and cities being "bad" or "immoral" began to change.

### Use of "Paradox"

Shepherd is saying that an arcade is a beautiful space of production (which is usually a rural space). So when that idea of a beautiful rural market is brought into the city through an arcade, it takes an urban space and makes it feel more rural while taking a rural aesthetic and making it more urban. He uses the term paradoxically to describe the combination of these opposite ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course a patch of ground in the city is not a conscious being that can choose to behave ethically or not. (Well, outside a science fiction novel or the beliefs of people with fringe philosophical ideas.) But the people who created that space and who use that space can have ideas about its proper use that involve ethical considerations. While it is meaningless to talk about the ethics of a rock in the sense of the rock making moral decisions, it is quite reasonable to talk about the ethics of a rock in the sense of people making moral decisions about how they use that rock. Using a rock as an example suddenly brings to my mind a news story I saw a while ago of a dispute between two neighbors, where at one point the one neighbor decided to put a very large rock blocking his neighbor's driveway. One could certainly question the ethics of that use of a rock.

The paradox the writer describes is that he sees an "arcade" as being a rural-like environment, but it is located within a city. It's not clear to me from the paragraph quoted why an arcade would be "rural" -- just because it's a big open space? I'm not sure -- but whatever his reasoning for that, he's saying that an arcade is a prominent feature of an urban environment, but is essentially rural, and so this is a paradox.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I updated my OP to provide more context. Does it help? Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: Sorry, the additional context still does not make clear to me why this is a "rural" space, but I don't think it's important to reply to your question. For whatever reason, that's how he sees it.